# Drupal Form API and BrainTree Exception Authentication

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms, braintree

When I create a Drupal form with the API and construct the form as necessary, Braintree returns an authentication exception.  When I take that same rendered HTML and output it on the page (skip the api), then it works.  I can't figure out why!

Below is the code that does not work.

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['user/payment/add'] = array(
    'title' => t('Add Card'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_add_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'weight' => 2,
  );
}

function my_module_add_form() {

  global $user;

  require_once 'sites/all/libraries/braintree/lib/Braintree.php';

  Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
  Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xxx');
  Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xxx');
  Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xxx');

  $customer = Braintree_Customer::find($user->uid);

  $trData = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::updateCustomerData(
    array(
      'redirectUrl' => 'http://www.xxx.com/user/payment',
      'customerId' => $user->uid
    )
  );

  $form['#action'] = url(Braintree_TransparentRedirect::url(), array('external' => true));
  $form['customer[first_name]'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
  );
  $form['customer[last_name]'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last Name'),
);
  $form['tr_data'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => htmlentities($trData),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Save')
  );

  return $form;
}
```

if instead I take that exact HTML output and do this with a normal_menu_item and the same credentials as above...

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['user/payment/add'] = array(
    'title' => t('Add Card'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'my_module_add_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'weight' => 2,
  );
}


function my_module_add_page() {

  global $user;

  require_once 'sites/all/libraries/braintree/lib/Braintree.php';

  Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
  Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xxx');
  Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xxx');
  Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xxx');

  $customer = Braintree_Customer::find($user->uid);

  $trData = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::updateCustomerData(
    array(
      'redirectUrl' => 'http://www.xxx.com/user/payment',
      'customerId' => $user->uid
    )
  );

    $output="

    <form accept-charset='UTF-8' id='tqcustom-billing' method='post' action='".Braintree_TransparentRedirect::url()."'>
    <div>
      <div class='form-item form-type-textfield form-item-customer-first-name'>
        <label for='edit-customer-first-name'>First Name </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-text' maxlength='128' size='60' value='' name='customer[first_name]' id='edit-customer-first-name'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-item form-type-textfield form-item-customer-last-name'>
        <label for='edit-customer-last-name'>Last Name </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-text' maxlength='128' size='60' value='' name='customer[last_name]' id='edit-customer-last-name'>
      </div>
      <input type='hidden' value='".$trData."' name='tr_data'>
      <input type='submit' class='form-submit' value='Save' name='op' id='edit-submit'>
    </div>
  </form>
  ";
  return $output;
}
```

it returns fine with a status code of 200.  something about drupal_get_form or drupal_render kills the environment that braintree needs to authenticate the form post.  What in the world could be causing this?  The browser HTML output is 100% exactly the same both ways, but the first way won't authenticate.

Please ask me for details and I'll supply them - desperate to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you are passing the output of `Braintree_TransparentRedirect::updateCustomerData` through `htmlentities` before displaying the form. This will cause ampersands to appear as &amp; instead of &. Since the tr_data field is signed with your API key, it must be exactly what is returned from `Braintree_TransparentRedirect::updateCustomerData`.

Disclaimer: I work for Braintree

Comment: Thanks John!  Can't believe I spent so LONG on this issue - that being said I can't believe I spent so LITTLE time setting up everything.  Braintree deserves a shout out right here.